# Initialization of objects in a vector

Tags: c++

Simple yes/no question (I think). If I declare the following at file scope:

```
struct SoundTouchExt
{
    SoundTouch sTouch;
    int channels;
    int sampleRate;
    float tempoChange;
    int pitchSemi;
    int bytesPerSample;
};

const int MAX_TRACKS = 16;

vector<SoundTouchExt> sProcessors(MAX_TRACKS);
```

with SoundTouch being a class with a public default constructor, should I get a valid object when I do this in a function:

```
SoundTouchExt& soundTouch = sProcessors.at(0);
SoundTouch& sTouch = soundTouch.sTouch;
```

I am expecting `sTouch` is a `SoundTouch` object constructed with the default constructor. Is there a hidden gotcha that I could be missing? I will go into more detail if needed.

Comment: As long as you don't add any elements to the vector, or do anything else that might invalidate `sProcessors[0]`.

Comment: Why would adding an element invalidate sProcessors[0]?

Comment: Because the vector may need to reallocate if there is not enough space for the new element (i.e. if `sProcessors.size() == sProcessors.capacity()` before the insertion). The previous elements would be copied over, but they would be different objects, so any references to the originals would become invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expectation is correct. You have 16 default-constructed instances of `SoundTouchExt` (each containing a default-constructed instance of `SoundTouch`).

Note that keeping the `SoundTouchExt` *reference* requires care, since modifying the vector in certain ways (e.g. adding an element to it) could invalidate the reference.

Comment: Not keeping the reference, and always calling sProcessors.at(0) should be fine, right? It will always be the object I'm expecting?

Comment: @svenoaks: In a word, yes.